# objects initialization fails C++

Tags: c++, object, initialization, initializer-list

i've been trying to debug the following code unsuccessfully,
the only thing i noticed that causes the program to crash is that "movies1" always gets the value 0x0 (like it's never initialized) and "d1" is being initialized with the default constructor instead the one specified in the "TestDirector" constructor.
all the other variables (int, char, string) are getting the right values.

I'd appreciate any kind of help.
thanks.

```
# include "gtest.h"
# include "Movie.h"
# include "Director.h"

class TestDirector: public ::testing::Test{
    protected:
    vector<Movie*>* movies1;
    string name1;
    int id1, age1;
    char gender1;
    string description1;
    Director d1;

        void SetUp(){
            cout<<"Setting up"<<endl;
        }
        void TearDown(){
            cout<<"Tearing down"<<endl;

        }
    public:
        TestDirector():
            movies1(new vector<Movie*>(0)), 
            name1("Director1 name"),
            id1(1),
            age1(1),
            gender1('m'),
            description1("Director 1 job description"), 
            d1(name1, 
               id1 , 
               age1, 
               gender1, 
               movies1, 
               description1)
        {
        }
};

TEST_F(TestDirector, StringPrintMatch) {
    ostringstream output1, output2;
    d1.print(output1);
    output2 << name1;
    EXPECT_EQ(output1.str(),output2.str());
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to initalize d1?

Comment: It looks like that he initialize d1 in TestDirector ctor

Comment: Not enough code here to give more than generalities. `vector<Movie*>* movies1;` A pointer to a vector of pointers is almost certainly the wrong choice. A vector of pointers might be an OK decision, [look into smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), but there is no need for `movies1` to be a pointer to a vector rather than a vector and a whole lot of downside. [The rule of three, for one thing.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Stop using raw pointers, and all these problems will go away

Comment: [I recommend an crafting a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and replacing the current question code with the MCVE if the MCVE doesn't expose and solve all of your problems.